# Linking Google accounts after registration in Trello

Tags: gmail, google, trello, authentication, profile

Originally, I registered using my email address (@gmail). Now I would like to link that account to my Google authentication credentials. Is this possible? Or do I need to create a new Trello account and add this new user as a project collaborator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to link the account specifically. You just use "Log in with Google Account" when you log in to Trello.
They automatically match you to your previously registered account if you used your gmail address for that.

Answer (score 1):

While Trello currently lets you add a password to an existing OpenID account, it doesn't let you add an OpenID account to a username/password account.

Currently, you can create a new account using your google account, and then transfer your boards/orgs to the new account.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same. Have a look at [your Google profile](https://profiles.google.com) whether [Connected Sites, Apps, and Services](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens) shows [trello.com](http://trello.com/).

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I hadn't tried to link it up. It auto-matched the two accounts as suggested by Turismo